# LoadGrammar(New Grammar(VOCABULARIO)) error

Tags: vb.net, voice

My form:

Error in this line:

```
REC.LoadGrammar(New Grammar(VOCABULARIO))
```

???????

Thanks.

```
Imports System.Speech.Recognition
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Globalization



Public Class Form1

    Dim REC As New SpeechRecognitionEngine
    Dim PALABRA As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("pt-BR")
        REC.RequestRecognizerUpdate()
        REC.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice()
        Dim VOCABULARIO As New GrammarBuilder
        VOCABULARIO.Append(New Choices("cc", "web", "word", "paint"))

        REC.LoadGrammar(New Grammar(VOCABULARIO))
        REC.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple)
        AddHandler REC.SpeechRecognized, AddressOf RECONOCE
        AddHandler REC.SpeechRecognitionRejected, AddressOf NORECONOCE
    End Sub

    Public Sub RECONOCE(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SpeechRecognizedEventArgs)

        Dim RESULTADO As RecognitionResult = e.Result
        Label1.Text = RESULTADO.Text.ToUpper
        Dim PROCESO As New Process
        Select Case RESULTADO.Text

            Case "cc"
                PROCESO.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2014\Dreamweaver.exe"
                PROCESO.Start()
            Case "web"
                PROCESO.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
                PROCESO.Start()
            Case "word"
                PROCESO.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe"
                PROCESO.Start()
            Case "paint"
                PROCESO.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Windows\System32/mspaint.exe"
                PROCESO.Start()
        End Select

    End Sub

    Public Sub NORECONOCE()
        Label1.Text = "Repita, por favor!"
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, and the question is formatted such that it is not possible to know what is text from code from error message. Please [edit] the question and format the contents so they are readable. Make it clear what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get. (For example, do not put error messages in the title -- the error message should be in the text of the question.)

Comment: Add `REC.RequestRecognizerUpdate()` before `REC.LoadGrammar()`.

Comment: i do it... but... same error...{"The grammar language does not match the language of the speech recognizer."}

Comment: I include:

Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Globalization

and

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("pt-BR")

in public class Form1 -> private sub form1_load

Comment: Please edit your question to show the latest version for your code.

Comment: Add This lines:


Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Globalization

And  this in Private Sub Form1_Load

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("pt-BR")
REC.RequestRecognizerUpdate()